# How to use a single config file for multiple osgi services

Tags: java, osgi, configuration-files

I am working with `OSGi R7` and have a case where it would be convenient to use a single config file for two seperate services, vice a new config file for each service.  I tried using the `@Component` name property to set a generic config file but this did not work (e.g. duplicate PID warning/error - see below). 
The other thing i tried was defining the service config interface in only one service and tried using it in both, but this doesn't appear to be working either since i'm not catching the breakpoint in my `@Activate` method of the second service.

```
@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "My 1st Service Config")
@interface FirstServiceConfig {

  String filePath() default "/path/to/my/file";

}
@Component(immediate = true, name = "com.my.generic.config", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, service = {
    FirstService.class })
@Designate(ocd = FirstServiceConfig.class)



@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "My 2nd Service Config")
@interface SecondServiceConfig {

  String filePath() default "/path/to/my/file";

}
@Component(immediate = true, name = "com.my.generic.config", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, service = {
    SecondService.class })
@Designate(ocd = SecondServiceConfig.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another developer here was able to figure out a solution to my problem looking into a different service configuration issue - long story short, the solution was to only set 1 configuration associated to the 1 PID, but then in the second service's activate method, you can access any service's configuration via the ConfigurationAdmin service, then retrieve the config value from the key:

```
@Reference
ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin;

@Activate
public void activate() throws IOException {
  Configuration conf = configAdmin.getConfiguration("pid.value.goes.here");
  Dictionary<String, Object> props = conf.getProperties();

  filePath = String.valueOf(props.get("configFilePath"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Components must have unique names. But you can use the [Component.configurationPid](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component.configurationPid--) element to specify the configuration pid(s) that should be use by the component. And multiple components can use the same configuration pid.